# How to store Images in Android Temporary in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I am making a webservice calls , from there i am getting data in json format : in each Row i am getting text,images,ids. I am getting a lot of rows from webservice. Now i want to display them with images one by one by click event. And if i make again same webservice call , then i want the old data no more, i will fetch new data.

**here what i planned:**
i dont want to fetch data with click event,instead i want to fetch data at once and later i will make static calls to display data.

```
I will store everyData in ArrayList <MyObject > myobj;
```

and i will fetch like

```
class MyObject
{
String name;
Bitmap image; or byte[] image;
String qualification;

getter and setter method.
}
```

In Activity class:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myobj=new ArrayList<MyObject>();

// suppose i am getting data in Array[Json Object] having image,name,qualification. 

for(i=0;i<jsonarray.length;i++){
MyObject m=new MyObject();
m.setName(jsonobj.get("name"));
m.setImage(jsonobj.get("Image"));  // i am confused here means how to convert into bitmap or byte array.
m.setQualification(jsonobj.get("qual"));
myobj.add(m);

}
```

// I am not sure how to exactly implement it.  please help me as i am confused due to image store.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Store Images in Your App Directory in External SD Card

Comment: if i am again calling same webservice calls , then already images will be there in Sd-card. But on server image name might be same but content might get change.

Comment: please check ,i have edited my question and give me suggession.

Comment: Also Add Image Local Path to the ArrayList so whenever new data is coming just delete the  Files Stored in SD-Card and Clear Array List and new data will be added to same ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

You just add the coming data into your database at the same time you will delete the old data from database.  Just these 2 queries will solve your problem.

Comment: I dont want to store data in sqlite. is it possible to store all data with images locally in ArrayList?

Comment: Why don't you want to store it into SQLite? What if your app crashes/is stopped? The one place you can "store" an arraylist is in memory, in this case.

Comment: what is the problem with this just delete the old data and the insert new row in table , its maintains always one row in your table and size of database is very small, just call a function firstly delete command and the insert command easily temporary storage